# How to make this more generic

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

**[code]**

```
private static IOrderedEnumerable<Film> OrderBy(this IEnumerable<Film> source, Func<Film, object> order, bool desc)
{
    if (desc) { return source.OrderByDescending(order); }
    return source.OrderBy(order);
}
```

**[Situation]**

Ofcourse, linq already implements a order by. I'm only trying to generize it more. Mostly just to learn things, it doesn't really add things other then that I can order by normally or order by descending with the same property.

**[Question]**

However I wish to make it more generic. Currently it only takes IEnumerable<T> and return IOrderedEnumerable<T> (where T currently is a movie. Custom model). 
Is there any general type of list, enumerable or something that covers all List, IEnumerable IOrderedEnumerable etcetc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's `IEnumerable<T>`.

Classes like `List<T>` implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, so a method that takes `IEnumerable<T>` can be used with most any collection.

---

You forgot to specify the generic parameter to the method: `OrderBy<Film>`.

The original `OrderBy` method also have a generic parameter for the type of the key. You might also want to use that, to make sure that the comparisons work properly, and that it doesn't do a lot of unnecessary boxing and unboxing:

```
private static IOrderedEnumerable<Film> OrderBy<Film, Key>(this IEnumerable<Film> source, Func<Film, Key> order, bool desc) {
  if (desc) { return source.OrderByDescending(order); }
  return source.OrderBy(order);
}
```